# How delete channel in image opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, shapes

I i have two different images(frames of video):

first image:

```
print(img1.shape)
(31,27,3)
```

second image:

```
print(img2.shape)
(31,27)
```

How i can delete on first image the value 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`img1.shape` variable returns height, width, channel of your current image.

> How i can delete on first image the value 3?

`3` refers to BGR channel in your image.
(I assume you read the image using `cv2.imread`)

You can convert to the gray-scale by

```py
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Now `print(img1.shape)`

and result will be:

```py
(31, 27)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `3` means that you have an RGB image, a color image.

If you want to make it grayscale, as I guess your second image is, use

```py
from skimage import color
gray_image = color.rgb2gray(image)
```